# Excel break lines doesn't pass to TextBox

Tags: c#, excel

I grab data from 15th cell of Excel, and passing it to `TextBox`. In result, break lines(**ALT+Enter**) doesn't pass, why?
Here is an example:

[image]

And i get a single string:

> Alex Ross096115976612/03/1990Test

And I want to see some characters if it possible where break lines should be. Or to get that 4 strings form 1 cell.

```
public DataTable ImportExceltoDatatable(string filepath)
        {
            string sqlquery = "Select * From [Лист1$]";
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            string constring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filepath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\"";
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constring + "");
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlquery, con);
            da.Fill(ds);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            DataRow[] O = dt.Select("'O' > '0'");
            Variables.Oo(O[0][14].ToString());
            return dt;
        }


private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ImportExceltoDatatable(Variables.path);
            textBox1.Text += Variables.O;
...
         }
```

Comment: There may be a display format while the actual text is devoid of line breaks.

Comment: Excel may be using a different line break character to what you're expecting... have you tried checking to see if there are any non-printable characters where the line breaks should be?

Comment: @gerrod, just watched in debugger. I get "\n" after each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your response to my comment, it sounds like a simple replace of `\n` will do the trick:

```
private string ConvertExcelLineBreaks(string text)
{
    return text.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Then you can do a slight modification on your `ImportExceltoDatatable` method:

```
public DataTable ImportExceltoDatatable(string filepath)
{
    // --- 8< ---
    var textFromExcel = O[0][14].ToString();
    Variables.Oo(ConvertExcelLineBreaks(textFromExcel));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `"\n"` by `"\r\n"` or by `Environment.NewLine` in result from excel.